# Laravel 5.5, 2 different databases and different models

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I can set 2 different databases in **config\database.php** with

`'conection'  => ['database01'  => [ ...`

`'conection'  => ['database02'  => [ ...`

And in the **model**  with

`protected $connection = '1database';`

`protected $connection = '2database';`

However, I want to use one **controller** and insert a conditional something like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

if (\Session::get('db')=='database01'){
    use App\Model01;
}else{
    use App\Model02;
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work.

```
public function index()
    {
    if ($baseDat1){
         $data= Data01::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
    }else{
        $data= Data02::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
    }        
}
```

Is it possible to do something like I want?

Answer (score 1):

Import both of them. And then just initiate the correct one within the `if` statement. Something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model01;
use App\Model02;
// ...

// Your controller
if (\Session::get('db')=='database01'){
    $model = app()->make(Model01::class);
} else {
    $model = app()->make(Model02::class);
}
// And now you can make queries with your $model like this
$results = $model->where(condition)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you , this solution is ok but I have to change all the models and all the calls inside the controller. It is ok, if I dont have other solution , is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement trait for this purpose. And use it in your models.

```
<?php

namespace App;

trait UsesTenantConnection
{
    /**
     * Get the current connection name for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConnectionName()
    {
        if (true) { //your condition here
            return 'database_01';
        } else {
            return 'database_02';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest option. You then can add `use UsesTenantConnection;` in your model

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default DB connection inside \App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot() method.

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    if (true) {
        $this->app['db']->setDefaultConnection('database_01');
    } else {
        $this->app['db']->setDefaultConnection('database_02');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but I only have to use diferent database in some models

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config database file with a helper function

1 - create helper function `changeDatabases($database)`

2 - change you config database

```
 if(database == 'baseDat1'){
 config(['database.connections.mysql.host' => 'newHost']);
 config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => 'newDatabase']);
 config(['database.connections.mysql.username' => 'newUsername']);
 config(['database.connections.mysql.password' => 'newPassword']);
}
```

3 - you must create two different model if they are not equal

the change is good the duration of the session

Comment: thank you but I only have to use diferent database in some models